# Where does my array change?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

This seemed like a really trivial issue, but I'm trying to write an array of `boolean`s to a file and then read them back into the array. I can verify that the file is being created properly:

```
true
false
true
false
false
false
```

But when I try to read it back, I end up with an array completely full of false. Here's my reading code:

```
    bools = new boolean[bools.length];

    try {    

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String temp;
        int i = 0;
        while (null != (temp = reader.readLine())) {
            bools[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(temp);

            // output what you read
            if (bools[i]) {
                System.out.println("true!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("false!");
            }
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BooleanFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BooleanFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // now output the resulting array
    for (int i = 0; i < bools.length; i++) {
        if (bools[i]) {
            System.out.println("true!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false!");
        }
    }
```

And here's the output I get:

```
true!
false!
true!
false!
false!
false!
false!
false!
false!
false!
false!
false!
```

The part that drives me bonkers is the array is set properly when I check it as I read (in the while loop), but it's wrong when I check the array at the end (in the for loop).

It may also be helpful to know that bools is a property of the class

Please excuse my noobishness.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (null != (temp = reader.readLine())) {
            bools[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(temp);

            // output what you read
            System.out.println(bools[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

You are putting everything at the same location. Increment your iterator variable and it will work.

Comment: Or just write `System.out.println(bools[i]);`

Comment: Happens with a lot of us!!

Answer (score 3):

Your not updating `i` value. First time your getting properly because your printing values directly from file.